# psycopg2 failed to connect abruptly while it worked yesterday

Tags: postgresql, nginx, flask, gunicorn, psycopg2

I'm working on deploying my flask application on Nginx with Gunicorn and as of yesterday I was able to access my website on a remote device and run queries that affected the database but for some reason today it has abruptly stopped and I get the following error in the log file.

```
      Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2117, in 
    _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3280, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at 
   "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  the database system is starting up

    (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
    [2022-09-29 15:20:41 +0300] [29652] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29652)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
    self.sleep()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
    ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
    gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/bin/gunicorn", line 8, 
    in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
    super().run()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
    self.stop()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
    time.sleep(0.1)
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
    File "/home/dancungerald/Documents/Python/SCHEYE/scheye_venv/lib/python3.8/site- 
    packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
    gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29673] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29673] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 
    (29673)
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29673] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29675] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29675
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29676] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29676
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29677] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29677
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29678] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29678
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29679] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29679
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29680] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29680
    [2022-09-29 15:20:42 +0300] [29681] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29681
    [2022-09-29 15:20:43 +0300] [29682] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29682
    [2022-09-29 15:20:43 +0300] [29683] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29683
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29682] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29682)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29681] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29681)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29683] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29683)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29679] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29679)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29678] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29678)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29677] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29677)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29680] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29680)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29675] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29675)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29676] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29676)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29675 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29678 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29681 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29682 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29677 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29679 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29680 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29676 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [WARNING] Worker with pid 29683 was terminated 
    due to signal 15
    [2022-09-29 15:46:12 +0300] [29673] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30879] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30879] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 
    (30879)
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30879] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30881] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30881
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30882] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30882
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30883] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30883
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30884] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30884
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30885] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30885
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30886] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30886
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30887] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30887
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30888] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30888
    [2022-09-29 15:46:14 +0300] [30889] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30889
```

It proposes that postgres is not running but I started the server and when I run `netstat -pln |grep 5432` I see that postgres is running on port 5432 so I doubt it's anything to do with the database connection.

If it helps, when it worked I was operating on my home network/wifi but it failed when I ran it today on an institutional network/wifi.

I have no idea what transpired for the app to behave this way. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "FATAL: the database system is starting up"  So, look into the database log files.  You told it to start, but it hasn't finished starting.  Starting up is usually fast, but apparently not this time.

Comment: This is the result when I run `netstat -pln |grep 5432 `                                                     `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8452/postgres       
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     108716   8452/postgres        /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`  so I believe the port is live and the database is running on that particular port

Comment: 1) **Do not** add relevant data in comment, update your question with the information. 2) The error is `FATAL:  the database system is starting up` not that it never started.  You have not followed @jjanes advice and looked at the Postgres logs for information. I would add to that looking at the system logs also.

Comment: To your question add the manner in which you are starting the application. Looks to me like a startup script that is not waiting for other applications to start.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled postgres to start up on boot with supervisord as per [this](https://nicksergeant.com/using-postgresql-with-supervisor-on-ubuntu-1010/) website. Here's what my supervisor configuration file looked like:

```
[program:appName]
directory=/Project/File/Directory/appName
command=/Project/File/Location/appName/app_venv/bin/gunicorn -w 9 run:app
user=username
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/appName/app.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/appName/app.out.log

[program:postgresql]
user=postgres
command=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data start              
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
redirect_stderr=true
```